# Read XML document stored in SQL Server with text datatype?

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is an example of the XML being stored in the SQL Server in a table column.
Like I have more than 10 columns, here I need to select the 4 columns last inserted

```
<Section xml:space="aligned" Paste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com">
<Para FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
<Run Text="this is the data to be select from here" />
</Para>
</Section>
```

this the table stracture

```
ID       Name         XMLContent                                  CreatedDate                   |       Modified



--------|------------|------------------|------------------------|-----------------------------------------
1       | CATEGORYID |<Section xml:space="aligned" Paste="False".|    |2011-04-05 12:28:15.030  |      
2       |    114     |<Section xml:space="aligned" Paste="False".|2011-04-05 12:28:15.030       |
```

should get the result

```
1   |this is the data to be select from here| 
2   |really a nice solution, |
```

i had saw the previous blogs i had used but this is for xml data type

```
SELECT TOP 5
    ID,
    XmlContent.value('(/Section/Para/Data/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM dbo.YourTableName
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

but i need for xml data stored in text datatype please suggest thanks

previous blog data getiing Null

```
DECLARE @xmltbl TABLE (ID INT, XmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @xmltbl(ID, XmlData) 
VALUES(1, '<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
<Run Text="Jubilee Financial Products is one of Europe’s largest structured product providers, working with 30 of the worlds’ largest banks. Jubilee is regulated in Ireland under MIFID and all products are regulated." />
</Paragraph></Section>'), 
(2, '<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left">
<Run Text="Jubilee Financial Products is one of Europe’s largest structured product providers, working with 30 of the worlds’ largest banks. Jubilee is regulated in Ireland under MIFID and all products are regulated." />
</Paragraph></Section> ');

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation')
SELECT 
    ID,
    DataText = XmlData.value('(/Section/Paragraph/Run/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM @xmltbl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would to be **convert** your column to datatype `XML` since `TEXT` is dead and should not be used anymore:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName
   ALTER COLUMN XmlContent XML
```

If you cannot do this, then you'll need to cast the `TEXT` to `XML` everytime you query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(XmlContent AS XML).value('declare namespace ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com";(/ns:Section/ns:Para/ns:Run/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM dbo.YourTableHere
```

Comment: Thnaks Marc_s i cannot do i wil try your answer now

Comment: Marc_s i am getting ID but i am getting      CAST(XmlContent AS XML).value('(/Section/Para/Data/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')  null vaue

Comment: did i make any mistake please let me know

Comment: Thanks Marc_s You helped me alot but ur answer above i am addind it is also giving null can u check once please

Comment: above added have small modification and i can not change anything please check that previous if it works taht's enough for me that is your answer only

Comment: in previous answer u had removed but i can't do it xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" any solution please

Comment: @Sadda-shutu: updated my response - you need to learn to **adapt** stuff you see to your own situation! Here, you have `<Run>` (instead of `<Data>` used in the earlier example) - so of course, you need to **adapt** the XPath expression accordingly! I can't just give you the code for all possible situations! Learn from the code!

Comment: yes ofcuse thanks for reply i wil try to lern let me try and thanks very much marc_s

Comment: Thanks Marc_s you guys are super even i got an idea in it and working fine thanks