# How to read all the nodes from XML stored in my database using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I am working on an asp.net c# application. Below `XML` is stored in my database as `Bookpoint` column as `text` data type.

I need get only all the `<Point>` nodes which are under different elements. I was thinking to get all those points using XQuery in SQL Server 2008

```
<BreezyCalc xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://microsoft.com">
  <Graph Foreground="#FF000000">
     <point>lines added</point>
  <Graph/>
  <Graph Foreground="#FF000000">
     <point>lines added</point>
     <point>two added</point>
     <point>lines added</point>
  <Graph />
  <Graph Foreground="#FF000000">
     <lines>
       <point>lines Removed</point>
       <point>lines added</point>
     <lines/>
  <Graph/>
<BreezyCalc/>
```

My table structure

```
PointID       Name         BookPoint                                  CreatedDate                   |
--------|--------------|---------------------------------------------|-------------------------------
1       | categoryname |<BreezyCalc xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http:|2011-04-05 12:28:15.030  |      
2       | category1    |<BreezyCalc xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http:|2011-04-05 12:28:15.030       |
```

Here I was expecting the result

```
1   |lines added
     lines added
     two added
     lines added  from firs column

2   |lines added, from second column
```

I had gone through this script

[Read XML document stored in SQL Server with text datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928126/read-xml-document-stored-in-sql-server-with-text-datatype)

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://microsoft.com')
SELECT 
    PointID,
    BookPoint.value('(/BreezyCalc/Graph/point)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM BooksTable
where id=1
```

but the result `"lines added "`

it giving me only one does I have any solution go get all the `<point>` nodes please help on this or please

Otherwise, could someone show me how I would get my graph data `<point>`

Comment: Why did you use `[1]`? That will return only the first `point` element.

Comment: If this is XML - why isn't the datatype of the column `XML` ?? Change it - once you've done that, we can talk about how to get the data....

Comment: thnks for reply Marc_s i had changed it to xml type then how could i Get all the nodes At a time

Comment: thanks for reply John Saunders insted of [1] wht could i use get all nodes i don't have any idea i just followed the above given url blog

Comment: Hi marc_s that i had refered blog is your's only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   PointID  
    ,T.C.value('(.)[1]','varchar(50)') AS point
FROM BooksTable
CROSS APPLY BookPoint.nodes('/BreezyCalc/Graph/point') as T(C)
where id=1
```

Comment: thanks for Reply Ritesh Kumar here i am getting error Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.  cause my xml data stored as text data type do we have any casting for it

Comment: i am trying to cast please check  SELECT PointID ,        
        CAST(T.C AS XML).value('(.)[1]','varchar(50)') AS point FROM BooksTable
         CROSS APPLY BookPoint.nodes('/BreezyCalc/Graph/point') as T(C) where id=1        same error

Comment: do we have cast it as xml

Comment: thanks Ritesh Kumar it's working i had done some mistake